# Is it possible to use code with argument through Inlinekeybuttons in Telegram python bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have code coded in command handler with argument if 1 then task1, if 2 then  task2. I can let it work, only by typing '/command 1' or '/command 2', to activate it.

Is it possible to add '1' or '2' argument immediately in the inlinekeyboardbutton?

My code for inlinekeyboard look like that right now.

I know that my buttons will trigger absolutely same code right now, but can't figured out how to set argument '1' for first button and '2' for second button.

```
options.append(InlineKeyboardButton("command with argument 1", callback_data="1"))
options.append(InlineKeyboardButton("command with argument 2", callback_data="2"))

#######

def callback_query_handler(update, context):
  
   input = update.callback_query.data
 
   if input == '1':
       self._command(update, context)

   if input == '2':
       self._command(update,context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is a built-in function and you should not override it.

Now I assume that `self._command` is the callback that you use for the `CommandHandler` that handles `command`.
Firstly (at least from your snippet it seems like) `self` is undefined within the `callback_query_handler` function.
Moreover, the `update` is the update with `update.callback_query` and `self._command` probably assumes that `update.message is not None` - so that's bound to make problems.
I suggest to

1. extract from `self._command` the logic that depends on the argument into a different function
2. call that function from both `self._command` and `callback_query_handler`

This function should probably take the argument as parameter. Note that in your corrent snippet the `if` s are basically pointless as in both cases you make the same call to `self._command`